# Button in the image XamarinForms

Tags: button, xamarin.forms

I have an image that I can scroll horizontally and I need to put a button on the image that will still be in the same position even if I scroll the image.
[Like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KKk6E.png)

My code:

```
<StackLayout>
    <Button WidthRequest="30" HeightRequest="30" BorderRadius="20" HorizontalOptions="Start" />
    <ScrollView Orientation="Horizontal" >
        <Image HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="Center" Source="mapasveta.png" />
    </ScrollView>
</StackLayout>
```

Comment: use a Grid or AbsoluteLayout to position the button on top of the image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Grid with no Row and now Columns now the button will overlap on ScrollView.

```
<StackLayout>
    
<Grid>
    <ScrollView Orientation="Horizontal" >
        <Image HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="Center" Source="mapasveta.png" />
</ScrollView>
<Button WidthRequest="30" HeightRequest="30" BorderRadius="15" HorizontalOptions="Start" VerticalOptions="Start"
 Margin="15"/>
</Grid>
    
</StackLayout>
```